# Where should I place PayPal auto-return parameters?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal

Is there a suggested place or method by which to insert PayPal auto-return parameters, so as to guide PayPay to return users to a thank-you page following a transaction?

I have created a pretty standard CiviCRM contribution page to handle membership signups for a small non-profit. The sign-up process works great, but once users are done clicking the "Agree and Pay" button on PayPal, they now have to click a "Return to ..." button (still on PayPal) before being redirected back to the CiviCRM thank-you page.

As I understand it, one can use a return parameter to tell PayPal where to send users once their transaction is done, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Any advice?

For context, if it matters, this PayPal Business account is used both for CiviCRM and a separate web store.

A couple references that have guided me so far (but not far enough :-) are...

- [Paypal IPN eCommerce Payment Transaction Integration Notes](http://www.davidtan.org/paypal-ipn-ecommerce-payment-transaction-integration-notes/)
- [Multiple Auto Return Urls](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/Multiple-Auto-Return-Urls/td-p/7228)

Answer (score 1):

The auto-return can be setup in your Paypal account.

- Login and click on your **Profile** (upper right), click on **Profile and Settings**.
- In the box on the left, click **My Selling Tools**.
- Under the Selling Online section, update your **Website Preferences**.
- On that page, make sure to **turn on Auto Return** and then **set your return URL** per the instructions.

[image: setting the return URL for PayPal]

Comment: Thanks, Allen! I really appreciate you taking time to answer my question. Because that Return URL is already in use by our web store and because further investigation showed that PayPal might not really fulfill my needs around membership renewals / cancellations, I signed up for an iATS account and have, by way of that, routed around this problem.